# Is there any way to label each desktop individually?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I'm usually working with 3x3 Desktops, with the tendency to separate them by active projects or clients for the workday (for example, all consoles going to project A on one desktop, all consoles going to project B on another).

This is fine in most cases, but when there's a lot of stuff going on at once it can quickly become confusing.

Is there some way to label a Desktop? Either on the 3x3 Grid view (when switching around with CTRL+ALT+Arrows), some kind of gnome plugin to just add a Box with a word in it, or a custom background for each desktop?

Maybe there's an obvious solution, but I never really played around with gnome. I still use the defaults.

Gnome Shell: 3.28.4

Ubuntu: 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: You may set a different background image for each desktop, or change interface colors, otherwise just use some kind of note-desktop widget like `sudo apt install xfce4-notes-plugin` and put a note-desktop widget on each of your desktops and set those to `always on top`.

Comment: Gnome uses extensions. Examples: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/ https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/551/workspace-labels/  both unmaintained though (no idea if those work). 1st link has a list of other possible extensions

Comment: PS you might just use any editor, like _gedit_ and set it to always been shown on top

Comment: @paladin Yeah I'm currently doing something similar, as a makeshift solution - but it's just not very practical long-term :)

Comment: @Rinzwind at this point, since the extension seems to be written with JS (and I'm really looking for something proper) I might end up just writing / maintaining my own solution then. I'll be looking into it, I guess!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, thanks to the comments and especially Rinzwind, I managed to find a solution:

Turns out, I was already using [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). While not obvious on how to do it, the extension offers support for custom labels:

1. Install and activate the extension.
2. Configure the extension - you can do this directly on the website (I didn't realize that). Make sure to turn workspace labels ON.

[image]

3. If you see the switcher now, it'll number each Workspace ("Workspace 1, 2, 3, etc"). Unless I memorize the numbers, that's not really useful at all. But there is a way to change the label.
4. Open a console, type `dconf-editor`. Navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/workspace-names`. Set "Use default value" to OFF and add an array of labels.

[image]

Labels go from left to right, top to bottom. If you have a 3x3 grid, and want to label the bottom left workspace, it's the 7th index in the array. If you want to just remove the default naming "Workspace X" for a particular workspace, just use `' '` (space); an empty string `''` won't work.

That's it! Works like a charm, at least if you use workspace-grid. I'm not sure if it's properly supported on later versions of Gnome, as the 1-star comments imply that there are issues.

Additional documentation can be found on https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid

**Please keep in mind that this extension is no longer in development.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do not hesitate to "accept" your own question. This is perfectly fine on this site. Accepting an answer hints users that at least a good solution can be found here. You still have like workspace indicators around - also in this context, your method to "label" these other than "1,2,3,4" is useful.

Comment: @vanadium Yeah I will do so in 2 days, if I don't forget (and no-one else has something better); I have to wait for the timer first. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: This solution also works with the (still actively maintained) “Space Bar” extension, _iff_ it’s “smart workspace names” are disabled. Adding this here because I had a similar problem using that extension with not wanting to manually rename each workspace after each restart anew.